# How to arrange datatable columns inside gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

My gridview is having a template field bound from the aspx designer. I'm binding a data table to it. Now my template field, which is having few action buttons, is coming as the first column. Is there any way to arrange the datatable columns before the template field?

Code from Designer for the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="JobListGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="View" CssClass="imgbutton" ToolTip="View Pdf" runat="server"
            CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' ImageUrl="~/Content/pdf.PNG"  CommandName="View" Width="36" Height="36" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("JobID", "OpenInNewWindow(\"{0}\").ToString()") %>' />
        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CS Code:

```
JobListGrid.DataSource = dataTableObj;
JobListGrid.DataBind();
```

The above code shows the grid view headers like :

```
TemplateField | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
```

I need the Templatefield to come last. The col1, col, col3 are getting from the datatable.

Comment: What do you mean by "prepend the datatable to it"? Can you give us an example, or show us some code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var columns = JobListGrid.Columns.CloneFields(); //Will get all the columns bound dynamically to the gridview.
var columnToMove = JobListGrid.Columns[0]; //My first column is Action Column
JobListGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(0);           // Remove it
JobListGrid.Columns.Insert(columns.Count - 1, columnToMove); // Moved to last
JobListGrid.DataBind();                    // Bind the grid .
```

This thing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your GridView like this, for controlling columns you `AutoGenerateColumns` must be disable.

```
<asp:GridView ID="JobListGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobID" HeaderText="JobID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JobName" HeaderText="Name" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="View" CssClass="imgbutton" ToolTip="View Pdf" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' ImageUrl="~/Content/pdf.PNG"  CommandName="View" Width="36" Height="36" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("JobID", "OpenInNewWindow(\"{0}\").ToString()") %>' />
                       </div>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: BoundField is specifying on runtime. This wont help.

Comment: With `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` the columns are generated runtime but, when you disable columns auto generating by setting `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` just the columns that declared by BoundField will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a template field for each column that you want from your datatable. Use a label inside your template field for displaying text using `<%#Bind("yourColumnName")%>` for text property. That way, you can arrangecolumns  in any order you wish for. Also set `autogenerate columns to false` in gridview. Something like

```
<asp:GridView ID="JobListGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="myDataTableColumn1">
        <ItemTemplate>        
           <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"
             Text='<%# Bind("yourDataTableColumnName") %>'></asp:Label>
       <ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
   <Columns>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="View" CssClass="imgbutton" ToolTip="View Pdf" runat="server"
                CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' ImageUrl="~/Content/pdf.PNG"  CommandName="View" Width="36" Height="36" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("JobID", "OpenInNewWindow(\"{0}\").ToString()") %>' />
            </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: How to bind the columns as it is done from the code behind? In this case i may need to bind the templatefield also from the code behind, right?

Comment: Nope, you just create the datatable & bind your gridview to the datatable as you are doing now. On your gridview, you set autogenerate columns to false & define template fields for each column to want. Inside each column, you drop a label control & use the Bind property as I said in my post to bind with desired column in your datatable.

Comment: My Column fields are dynamic. It cannot be defined directly to the template. I found another work around. It worked. I'll paste it here